# Duration outside the UK

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, repeat-visits

I’ve been going to the Uk frequently, for how long do I have to stay outside the United Kingdom in order for them not to think that I’m a frequent visitor the next time I visit?

Comment: Different wording but essentially yet again you’ve posted the same question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142520/us-citizen-frequent-visits-to-the-uk

Comment: Not the same question at all! This time I’m asking about the duration outside the UK not my actual case

Answer (score 4):

There's no fixed rule.

An often stated rule of thumb is that if -- averaged over several  visits -- you're spending more time outside the UK than in, you *probably* won't be considered to be living in the UK through frequent or successive visits. But it's really always a concrete judgement based on *both* your travel history *and* your answers when you're asked about the purpose of your visits, *and* how credible you seem in person.